# can we pass instance of class in switch() argument?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I know how to pass a string or int as argument in switch(). But I want to know passing instance of class in switch() and to get the method in CASE:..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Why must you use switch? You can just use `instanceOf` with `if` statements if this is really what you need.

Comment: You can't do that with switch

Comment: This is what non-final method overrides are for. You're looking for the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: ok.. thank you.. can u tell me.. that how to use instanceOf with if statement with example?..

Comment: `if (someObject instanceOf someClass) {}`

Answer (score 2):

In a word - no.

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

Comment: how to use [Enum] type in switch statement?.. plz tell me with example. i am fresher